# Can the notion of algebraic closedness be generalized to the rings with zero divisors?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, hypercomplex-numbers

Is there a notion of rings that are algebraically closed except for the roots of polynomials with coefficients that are divisors of zero?

For instance, it seems that any polynomial of non-zero-divisor-coefficients in tessarines/bicomplex numbers has roots in tessarines.

So, they seem to be more algebraically closed despite being not a field.

On the other hand, split-complex numbers are not algebraically closed in this sense, and their algebraic closure seems to be tessarines.

For instance, the equation $z^2-j=0$ has 4 roots at tessarines, none of which is purely split-complex:

$$z_1=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)j$$

$$z_2=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)j$$

$$z_3=-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)j$$

$$z_4=-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)j$$

If we consider other functions, such as the logarithm, it also brings us out from the set of split-complex numbers, even if zero divisors are not involved ($\ln j=\frac{i \pi }{2}-\frac{i j \pi }{2}$).

Comment: You are free to invent such a notion. Since tessarines are isomorphic to $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$, they indeed are algebraically closed in this sense (indeed, it makes clear that any polynomial with at least one coefficient other than the constant term not a zero divisor will have a root)

Comment: For noncommutative division rings, really weird things can happen.  For instance, degree $n$ polynomials over the quaternions can have more than $n$ roots.  So you might want to stick with commutative rings.

Comment: @PaceNielsen in quaternions they can have infinite number of roots, in tessarines, no more than $n^2$ (it is commutative).

Comment: @Anixx Yes, but it has zero-divisors and the quaternions do not.  My point was, even without zero-divisors, noncommutative rings can have weird behaviors involving polynomials.

Comment: If you take an infinite direct product of copies of $\mathbb{C}$, you get uncountably many roots of the polynomial $x^2+1=0$.  So who's to say that the tessarines are more algebraically closed than this bigger direct product?  You will need to be precise how you frame your closure property.

Comment: No problem to consider commutative unital rings where every monic polynomial is a product of monic linear polynomials. Such ring can be constructed following the same kind of tower as the algebraic closure of a field. For non-commutative rings you can still say that $x$ commutes with $R$ in $R[x]$ but $\sum_{j=0}^d c_j x^j=\prod_{i=1}^d (x-a_i)$ won't give that $\sum_{j=0}^d c_j r^j=\prod_{i=1}^d (r-a_i)$ for $r\in R$ not in the center.